# Clearing the screen in C using Cygwin

Tags: c, console, cygwin

I have attempted several approaches to clearing the screen in C, under Cygwin. system("cls") and system("clear") don't work when the application is running, giving errors that say in effect, "that command doesn't exist". I'm testing a c application that is going to end up on a micro-controller and operate an LCD screen, and the testing code needs to output the monochrome LCD data to the console each time it changes. The state changes have the potential to occur very quickly, and visualizing the changes properly really means I need an honest-to-goodness screen clear to occur in a programmatic way. Any ideas how this might be done?

Comment: You probably want to install ncurses.

Comment: Try `printf("%c[2J", 27);`. If that works, then yeah, you probably want to use the curses library.

Comment: Sweet, thanks. I'll give these ideas a go!

Comment: If you are using Cygwin, I assume that you are using Windows. Try `system("cls")`

Comment: I used system("cls"): "cls": command not found.